# .net 4.5 web forms c# Context of a variable isn't found in Codefile

Tags: .net, webforms, code-behind, saml-2.0

I'm attempting to build a SAML 2.0 Claims aware web form and got [some code from MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh987037).

I understand what the problem is, I just don't know how to solve it:

The signedIn variable (and others..) in the cs code behind page doesn't know that it is defined and associated to the asp variable in the aspx page.
{The name 'signedIn' does not exist in the current context}

I have tried tweaking the Inherited value, Class name, I've ransacked the internet and this site to look for ideas. (which led me to steps to build a designer.cs file) Still no results..  (Even though in the end I'm going to try to convert this solution to a single-file page model, as it will be easier for me to implement.)

Help?

> Default.aspx.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Threading;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace TestApp
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;

            if (claimsPrincipal != null)
            {
                signedIn.Text = "You are signed in.";

                foreach (Claim claim in claimsPrincipal.Claims)
                {
                    //claimType.Text = claim.Type;
                    //claimValue.Text = claim.Value;
                    //claimValueType.Text = claim.ValueType;
                    //claimSubjectName.Text = claim.Subject.Name;
                    //claimIssuer.Text = claim.Issuer; 
                }
            }
            else
            {
  //              signedIn.Text = "You are not signed in.";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Default.aspx:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1><asp:label ID="signedIn" runat="server" /></h1>
    <asp:label ID="claimType" runat="server" />
    <asp:label ID="claimValue" runat="server" />
    <asp:label ID="claimValueType" runat="server" />
    <asp:label ID="claimSubjectName" runat="server" />
    <asp:label ID="claimIssuer" runat="server" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

Killed the entire aspx page. created a new one through the studio tools, then merged the aspx and cs files together.

Still not sure what went wrong (inheritance linking incorrectly, etc..) but code is now compiling.. Now to add the logging functionality as described above, and then actually add my own functionality..

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I've done this, but I find enabling logging to be a good first step to finding out what is going on.  Some instructions on enabling logging can be found here:

[How To: Enable WIF Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj161102(v=vs.110).aspx)

Try naming the log with ".svclog" extension, then you can double-click to view it in the SvcTraceViewer tool, which makes it easier to dig for the problem messages.  More details on that here:

[Service Trace Viewer Tool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: That is very useful, Thanks Dan! Unfortunately the problem I am experiencing is within compiling the code given from the MSDN website.. But once this gets compiled and I'm making WIF requests, that will be invaluable.

Answer (score 0):

ClaimsPrincipal exposes a collection of identities, each of which is a ClaimsIdentity. The ClaimsIdentity implements IIdentity from which you could utilize the IsAuthenticated property that indicates whether the user has been authenticated.  This is a boolean true/false value.

Comment: Um.. not sure where you were going with this. But one of the tests I tried was to comment out all the code involving claims, (PageLoad consisted of only the signedIn assignment.) and it still had the same context error.. Thanks though!